# Cover full background at border-radius

Tags: css

Does anybody know how I can remove the green border around the corners if i click the dropdown item?

I added the following CSS:

```
.navbar-nav li {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    border: 0px solid black !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    background-color: green !important;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

Please have a look at my [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/PdyLw/).

[image]

Kind regards, shub

Comment: If you mean the small overlaying pixels around the "Dropdown" element, the only solution I can think of is to make the gray bg have a smaller border-radius.

Comment: Do you mean you want the green to disappear if it is the page that is currently open? It's not clear when you want to remove it.

Comment: I want to disappear the small green border of the item "dropdown".

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the solution. The declarations must be on the `<a>` tag.

```
.navbar-nav li > a, .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    border: 0px solid black !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Check als my [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/wqxu9/).